# Is it possible to hide the workspaces thumbnails in the application launcher?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

Is it possible to remove the workspaces thumbnails under the search bar in the application launcher to make more room for the icons?

**Edit:** With this change I'm hoping to have 4 rows of icons instead of just 3 in the applications grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excellent [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) extension can do that. The recommended way to install it is by using the Extension Manager app (just open a terminal and run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager` to install it).

To install the extension from Extension Manager, follow these steps:

1. Open Extension Manager and click the *Browse* tab.
2. Search for "just perfection" and click *Install* to install the extension.

   [image: Extension Manager Browse]
3. Go to the *Installed* tab and press the cog button next to *Just Perfection* to open the extension's preferences.

   [image: Just Perfection preferences]
4. Click *Visibility* on the bottom of the preferences window.
5. Find and disable *Workspace Switcher*.

   [image: Just Perfection disable Workspace Switcher]

**Note:** When this answer was written, the OP hadn't mentioned anything about also wanting to have more rows of icons in the applications grid. However, it answers exactly the main question, which is what most people would want to do, so I'm leaving it here. For how to also change the number of rows in the applications grid, please see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425450/618353).

Comment: Thanks, that did remove the Workspace Switcher, I was hoping that would allow 4 rows of icons instead of just 3. I guess that is not going to be possible. I will accept this as the answer. The grid does look cleaner  without the WS Switcher so it's an improvement.

Comment: I have added another answer that shows how you can also have 4 rows of icons. However, that was important information that should have been mentioned in your question. In the future, please make sure to be more specific about what you want to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent extension that allows for removing workspaces from overview is [Shell Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4254/shell-configurator/). Adjust accordingly and follow the steps 1-3 of [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425445/618353) to install it and open the extension's preferences window. Then:

4. Click *Configurations* on the top bar of the window.
5. In the *Workspace* section disable *Workspace Switcher Visibility*.

   [image: disable Workspace Switcher Visibility]

This extension also allows for changing the size of the app grid. So, to have 4 instead of 3 rows, go to the *App Grid* section of the extension's preferences and change the *Row Size* to 4.

[image: Shell Configurator row size option]

Comment: I uninstalled Just Perfection (JP), installed Shell Config (SC), and the Workspace Switcher Visibility toggle in SC did not work. So I had to reinstall JP. The combination of the 2 is working for what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart GNOME Shell to make it work. You can restart by pressing `Alt`+`F2`, entering "r", and pressing `Enter`.